# SSH Permission Denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I am trying to connect to SSH for the first time. But it says

```
The authenticity of host '[<host>]:<port>' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[<host>]:<port>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@<host>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Is there a breach or something?

Comment: what are the permissions of files in `.ssh` directory? And also what is the permission of `.ssh` directory itself

Comment: There is only one user - root.

Comment: Did you copy the public key to the server? Also, allowing `root` to login can pose a security risk.

Comment: @DeshBhakt, will you answer the questions?

Comment: @RomeoNinov As there is only root user, permissions are rwx for the root.

Comment: @Panki I did not copy any key to the server.

Comment: Add in to the question the result of `ls -ld ~/.ssh` and `ls -l ~/.ssh`

Comment: The problem is simple: The server only allows authentication with keyfiles. You have not placed your public key on the server. Therefore, you can't authenticate. There is no breach.

Comment: @Panki has it. You should post it as an anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two messages there.

The first is telling you that you don't yet know the fingerprint of the public key of the machine that you are connecting to. Before accepting it, check that the fingerprint is correct, by transiting via a separate secure channel (it is ok if someone else sees it, but they must not be able to replace it with their own).

The second part `root@<host>: Permission denied (publickey).` is a little ambiguous. But here are some things to check:

`sshd` (the server), is usually configured to block root login. You need to add a new user, with `sudo` permissions. Or a **less good** solution is to change the configuration of `ssh`, to allow root login.

Then check, that you:

- Put your public key into `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`?
- Set the permission so that no other groups or other can read or write to `~root/.ssh`, or the files in it, but root can at least read.
- Add your key to your agent (`ssh-add`).

If that does not work, then turn on verbose mode `-v` or `-vv` or `-vvv`, start with one, and increase as needed.

If that does not work, then look at the logs at the remote end.